# How to display all the data in MySQL with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to display all the values in my column even the **null** value.

Below is my code that displays all the columns data included null but it doesn't display the latest date.

```
 SELECT 
  MEMB.LAST_M,
  MEMB.MEMB_N,
  PrintDate
FROM
  MEMB 
  INNER JOIN tblPrint 
    ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N
```

[image: img1]

This code however displays the **latest dates** but doesn't display all the columns even the null values.

```
    SELECT 
  MEMB.LAST_M,
  MEMB.MEMB_N,
  MAX(PrintDate)
FROM
  MEMB 
  INNER JOIN tblPrint 
    ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N 
 WHERE tblPrint.`PrintDate` IN (SELECT tblPrint.`PrintDate` FROM tblPrint) GROUP BY MEMB.`LAST_M`
```

[image]

Comment: This is a redundant condition `tblPrint.PrintDate IN (SELECT tblPrint.PrintDate FROM tblPrint)`...might as well write `1 = 1`.

Comment: I already removed it! Thanks for noticing my query

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to use **LEFT JOIN** instead of INNER JOIN. Without seeing the DB structure, I have no way to test to be sure, but I've run into the same issue before. LEFT JOIN fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't change anything. IDK how to create a db structure, I can't show any to you as of now

Answer (score 0):

The problem to your query is your WHERE clause you could try removing it and you will get the NULL values.

```
SELECT 
  MEMB.LAST_M,
  MEMB.MEMB_N,
  MAX(PrintDate)
FROM
  MEMB 
  INNER JOIN tblPrint 
    ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N 
GROUP BY MEMB.LAST_M, MEMB.MEMB_N
```

Comment: A # in MySQL indicates what follows is a comment. And MySQL does not have #tables.

Comment: Forgot to remove sorry. I test it in SQL Server thats why i put it to temporary table. :)

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 8, [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) were implemented, so you can now include inline aggregates within a unit level query. Specifically you can add a new column to original query for *Latest_Date*:

```
SELECT 
  m.LAST_M,
  m.MEMB_N,
  p.PrintDate,
  MAX(PrintDate) OVER(PARTITION BY m.MEMB_N) AS Latest_Date
FROM
  MEMB m
INNER JOIN tblPrint p
  ON m.MEMB_N = p.MEMB_N
```